# Does `cfn-init` execute new commands (of a configSet) during a stack-update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Having a Configset as in this [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands):

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
    "configSets" : {
        "ascending" : [ "config1" , "config2" ],
        "descending" : [ "config2" , "config1" ]
    },
    "config1" : {
        "commands" : {
            "test" : {
                "command" : "echo \"$CFNTEST\" > test.txt",
                "env" : { "CFNTEST" : "I come from config1." },
                "cwd" : "~"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

If i add a command/modify the existing one as follows:

```
"config1" : {
        "commands" : {
            "test" : {
                "command" : "echo \"$CFNTEST\" > test.txt",
                "env" : { "CFNTEST" : "I come from config1." },
                "cwd" : "~"
            },
            "test2" : {
                "command" : "echo \"$CFNTEST\" > test2.txt",
                "env" : { "CFNTEST" : "I come from config2." },
                "cwd" : "~"
            }
        }
    }
```

Will the file `test2.txt` be created? If yes what happends if i modify `"env"` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these commands are only being run during cfn-init then they will not be run during a stack update. Only new instances will run the updated commands.

You need to use [cfn-hup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html) to re-run the cfn-init if you've updated the stack.